# Actor-critic action-value update

Tags: reinforcement-learning, actor-critic

I'm reading about Actor-Critic in [lilianweng](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2018-02-19-rl-overview/#deadly-triad-issue), and I'm wondering about [image: lil]

why is this the action-value function update? what function are we taking the gradient of here?

Comment: take a MSE between Q(s) and r+Q(s'), do 1 step of derivation of the gradient and you will end up with that formula (in other words, it's just a convoluted version of the mean squared error gradient)